# How can I view, calculate and show total price with this form?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <img src="image/frod001.gif" alt="" />
    <p class="item_name">Fishing rod model 001</p>
    <span class="item_price">BND $189.95</span><br/>            
    Qty: <input type="text" class="item_quantity" value="1" style="width:20px;"/><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="calculateText();" value="add to cart" />
</div>
```

I am new to coding and Javascript. I want the button working but without PHP, just Javascript

Comment: what exactly do you want on button click?
can you please specify your requirements?

Comment: Are you okay with using jQuery? It's considerably easier to learn than pure javascript, and dramatically less typing...

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where is your javascript and what errors/problems have you encountered?

Comment: Don't expect people to write you a complete function from a scratch. This is the wrong place for things like "please, do my homework".

Comment: @gibberish I don't recommend start using jQuery without learn plain Javascript.

Comment: @Carlangueitor I did... became productive 10x faster. Now fleshing in what I don't know about js, but fully functional in jQ. I do agree with you, though -- "in a perfect world." Then again, if OP is a student then you are totally correct.

Comment: this are just the scratch guys,

here are the .js file
function calculateText(){
var price=document.getElementById("price").innerText
var quantity=document.getElementsByClassName("item_quantity")[0].value
var total=price*quantity
alert("total: $"+total)

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your html, change the span into this:

```
<span class="item_price">BND <label id="price">189.95</label></span><br/>
```

and the js:

```
function calculateText(){
var price=document.getElementById("price").innerText
var quantity=document.getElementsByClassName("item_quantity")[0].value
var total=price*quantity
alert("total: $"+total)

}
```

Comment: how can i call it in the "document.write"? for the total price

Comment: when did you want this code to be executed? at page load? You could call this function from anywhere inside the html by simply writing:
  calculateText()

Comment: i change alert("total: $"+total) to
document.write("total: $"+total)

then i put calculateText() in the html. BUt all my page is gone, only the total price appear

whats the problem?

Comment: if you want to show the price within the same page, then add a text box/label next to the button and print the total price in it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/KgAe4/4/ :

```
<div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
    <img src="image/frod001.gif" alt="" />
    <p class="item_name">Fishing rod model 001</p>                                  
    <span class="item_price">BND $189.95</span><br/>                                
    Qty: <input type="text" class="item_quantity" value="1" style="width:20px;"/><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:calculateText();" id="calculateText" value="add to cart" />                          
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#calculateText").on("click", function(){
    var price = $(".item_price").text();
    var priceSplit = price.split("$");
    var realprice = parseFloat(priceSplit[1]);
    alert(realprice);
    var quantity = $(".item_quantity").val();
    alert(realprice*quantity);
});
```

**Javascript**

```
function calculateText(){
    var price = document.getElementsByClassName("item_price")[0].innerHTML;
    var priceSplit = price.split("$");
    var realprice = parseFloat(priceSplit[1]);
    var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("item_quantity")[0].value;
    alert(realprice*quantity);
}
```